# How to change tast_struct current into specific task_struct in x86?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

In high level, I tried to de-couple system call into two parts and my question occurs in kernel part. I tried to invoke function stored in system call table. Before invoking it, I need to switch current task information to user's (The reason I need to do this is that if I request `getpid()`, I need to know `task_struct` of one who requests `getpid` in user space).

For example:

```c
// memorize who actually request system call
task_struct *target = current;
.
.
context switch
.
.
// change task status to user space who request system call (target)
... how to do it?
// call specific system call
(sys_call_ptr_t *)syscall_table)[num](reg)
// restore task status back to original one
...
```

I know `current` can't be l-value, I'm looking for the answer about how to pretend current task is user's (`target`) and then call system call. After that, restore current task back to original one.

Edit:
The thing I want to achieve is to separate calling system call into 2 parts, which can avoid interrupt occur to handle system call. The way I make it is using shared memory between kernel and user space. In this shared memory, it records information about request from user space. In kernel part, I can know some information about requests of user gave and do corresponding task by looking up system call table and then calling it. Unfortunately, the information I have in shared memory is not enough. For example, I didn't have `task_struct current` of request asker in user space. As a result, calling `getpid` will not get the real ID of request asker in user space (This is also why I try to change `current` status and then call `getpid`, then result will be desired). I think get the `current` of asker in user space is the general solution for all system call.

Comment: You can't normally just do that. The other task might be executing on a different CPU for example, or even if in same CPU, there's current state (register values, stack) that would somehow need to be changed for the operation and restored back. Can you tell what you want to achieve? Maybe there's another way

Comment: There're shared memory between user and kernel. Then, I fill some data(system call number and its parameter) into it in user space and I do task (call system call) depend on those data in shared memory.

Comment: That doesn't really explain. Maybe try rewording. The reason I'm asking is that it's quite possible there are other simpler approaches. Maybe you could hook into target task with `ptrace` for example.

Comment: Hi, I've update my question and describe more what I want to do. Please tell me if it not clear enough. Thanks

Comment: In one thread you cannot use context of other thread. Instead, in the user space create an **additional thread**, which could be used by the kernel part (module) to run "delayed syscalls".

Comment: It's still not clear what you're actually trying to achieve. You describe what you're doing, but what's the actual problem here? To get the pid, you don't need `current`, you could save that `task_struct` (or even the pid/tgid which is in that struct) on device file open, for example, and then look it up when required.

Comment: Besides system call number and its arguments, I think there're something  I missed to call function in system call table properly. This is where I stuck.

Comment: The need of `current` is solution I guessed, by tracing `getpid` and found it need `current` which I didn't store in share memory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, can you describe more about user thread used by kernel part? Thanks!

Comment: I mean that from additional user thread you could use a special syscall or a syscall with special parameters, like `ioctl` on a character device created by you. The kernel code which is executed during processing that syscall works in the context of the desired program. Well, this additional thread would have different pid, but this fact is rarely important. The more important that this additional thread has the same address space, open file descriptors and may other things.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks. ioctl really help to solve part of problem. But it only solve IO-based syscall(`write`, `open`..). How about other non-IO-based syscall?

Comment: "How about other non-IO-based syscall?" - What is wrong with non-IO-based syscalls? Note, that primary usage of a syscall in Linux is to be processed in the thread which calls it, not in the other thread.

Comment: Yes, you're right(syscall in Linux is to be processed in the thread which calls). Actually, I tried to delayed syscall and use kernel thread to execute it later. The reason I asked "non-IO-based syscalls" is trying to find some solution to achieve it like `ioctl` did(delayed syscall).